# How to find the difference between oldest date and most recent date for each column after grouping by that column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am working with a table in SQLite3 on Python, and the table has four attributes -

```
ID, added(date when course added to subsection), course_id, course_subsection_title
```

Of these, the date_added attribute contains the date the course was added to the course_subsection, the course_id contains the ID of the course added, and the ID contains the ID of the course_subsection. The query I have to write groups the courses by the course_subsections, and then calculates the number of days passed between the oldest course added and the most recent course added to the particular course_subsection. I have a query for it as follows, but it appears to be working incorrectly -

```
query =  '''
        SELECT 
          course_subsections.ID as id,
          CAST((JulianDay(max(course_subsections.added)) - JulianDay(min(course_subsections.added))) as INTEGER) as num_days_passed
        FROM course_subsections
        WHERE course_subsections.ID = (
                              SELECT course_subsections.ID 
                              FROM course_subsections
                              GROUP BY course_subsections.ID
                              )
        ORDER BY num_days_passed DESC
     '''
```

This isn't working how it should, however. I am very new to SQLite, and still have some confusion about how nested subqueries work in general. Can you help me out with where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `WHERE` clause.
It filters out all the `ID`s but one of the table:

```
SELECT ID,
       CAST(JulianDay(MAX(added)) - JulianDay(MIN(added)) AS INTEGER) AS num_days_passed
FROM course_subsections
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY num_days_passed DESC;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sJBaHZBj).